# No build.xml file found when running an eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, gwt, ant

I am very new to gwt and in fact I don t really understand it.

I have a web project that had already been developped. I just want to change the toolbar that requires gwt in a RichTextToolbar.java file. So I downloaded Eclipse and its gwt plugin.

In a precedent question, I had the answer that I should take thes only file RichTextToolbar from my php/html directory, put in the src folder of my eclipse web application project; then run it and finally taking back the compiled files from the war folder and put it in my php/html directory.

Now, the problem is that when I debug or run the files in eclipse, I am told to choose ant. And then I have a message that no build.xml file is found. Could anyone help?

Best,
Newben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to compile the Java code in GWT to Javascript, then you can use 'Compile GWT Project' option under GWT menu in Eclipse.